# Create a linked server on a remote server ? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a linked server on a remote server. I know how to create it on the same server that I run the script in .

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = @name, @srvproduct=N'oracle', @provider=N'MSDAORA', @datasrc= @sursadate
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=@nume,@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=@username,@rmtpassword=@password
```

but how can I define that I want the linked server to be created on another server also using a script that I run it on the server I am on (not the same one that i want the linked server to be created on)? Is there a way to define an ip adress to where it should be created?

To be more clear for example: I'm running a script on a server 0.0.0.1, but I want the linked server to be created on another server 0.0.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you already created db server 0.0.0.2 as linked server into 0.0.0.1
then you only you can run this on 0.0.0.1.

```
EXEC [linked_server_name_for_0.0.0.2].master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = @name, @srvproduct=N'oracle', @provider=N'MSDAORA', @datasrc= @sursadate

EXEC [linked_server_name_for_0.0.0.2].master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=@nume,@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=@username,@rmtpassword=@password
```